# Do something before leaving page using navigation drawer menu icon

Tags: flutter, menu, navigation-drawer, flutter-alertdialog

In Fluter, I have some pages with an `AppBar` that shows the menu icon of the navigation drawer that it is used to navigate among distinct pages. Some of this pages allow the user to edit some data. So, I would like to ask for confirmation when the user clicks the menu icon without saving the editions she has made, but I have not found a way to override the (equivalent to the) `onTap` for the navigation menu icon.

There are solutions when a bottom navigation bar is used, and solutions that detect when the page has been popped, but I need the confirmation dialogue to be shown on the page being closed before the closing takes place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done simply by controlling the drawer through the global key, passed to the `Scaffold`, and specifying explicitly the `leading` parameter of `AppBar`:

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      drawer: const Drawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: DrawerButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final state = _key.currentState;
            final isOpen = state?.isDrawerOpen ?? false;

            if (!isOpen) {
              final close = await showDialog<bool>(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  title:
                      const Text('Are you sure you want to close this page?'),
                  actions: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                      child: const Text('Close'),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
              if (close ?? false) state?.openDrawer();
              return;
            }
            state?.closeDrawer();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```